# Why am I getting amp-script "could not find element" error?

Tags: amp-html

**Summary: When I try to use an amp-script tag with a script attribute, it claims not to see the script.**

Here is the code that is not working:

```
<amp-script layout="container" script="navToggleScript">
  <h3 class="nav-toggle icon"><a href="#navigation">Menu</a></h3>
</amp-script>
<script type="text/plain" target="amp-script" id="navToggleScript">
  document.querySelector(".nav-toggle.icon").textContent += 'Hello world!';
</script>
```

I have tried 1) adding name="navToggleScript" to the script tag and 2) making the script a child of the amp-script instead of a sibling. No matter what I do I still get the following error in Chrome, Firefox Dev Edition and Safari: `[ amp-script ] amp-script[script="navToggleScript"].js could not find element with # navToggleScript . error.js:195:8`. What am I doing wrong? It seems to me that I am following the instructions in the [documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script) to the letter. I would be grateful for any insight into this!

Comment: what happens when you use an absolute URL for the script source?

Comment: Using an absolute URL doesn't help, I'm afraid.

Comment: did you declare: `<script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js"></script>`

Comment: also see the section on error messages on this page: https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/#state-manipulation

Comment: Yes, the custom-element declaration was made in the <head> with the exact code quoted by Jay Gray.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

I think it's just a syntax error in the code. You didn't show all your code.

Also amp-script often requires a user event, read here: https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/#user-gestures

Here is a working example(it doesn't work in the stackoverflow editor):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ⚡>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My AMP Page</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="self.html" />
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="amp-script-src" content="sha384-uXoWENIGAIDx8-Kbo-aKOCJyr7HFCkg_jyDDPOKy1fHU1gexRU_AbvuDtCcKaFkD" />
    <style amp-boilerplate>
      body {
        -webkit-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
        -moz-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
        -ms-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
        animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      }

      @-webkit-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }

        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }

      @-moz-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }

        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }

      @-ms-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }

        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }

      @-o-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }

        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }

      @keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }

        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <noscript>
      <style amp-boilerplate>
        body {
          -webkit-animation: none;
          -moz-animation: none;
          -ms-animation: none;
          animation: none;
        }
      </style>
    </noscript>
    <style amp-custom></style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <amp-state id="counter">
      <script type="application/json">
        0
      </script>
    </amp-state>

    <h1>My AMP script</h1>
    <amp-script layout="container" script="navToggleScript">
      <h3 class="nav-toggle icon"><a href="#navigation">Menu</a></h3>
      <button type="button">Button</button>
      <span class="counter" [text]="counter">0</span>
    </amp-script>
    <script type="text/plain" target="amp-script" id="navToggleScript">
      const icon = document.querySelector('.icon');
      const btn = document.querySelector('button');
      let myCounter = 0;
      btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        icon.textContent += 'Hello world!';
        myCounter += 1;
        AMP.setState({counter: myCounter});
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```